# Cannot observe LiveData<MutableList<T>> from ViewModel in my fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

MyFragment.kt:

```
viewModel.studentsTemp.observe(this, Observer {
    adapter.submitList(it)
})
```

MyViewModel.kt

```
private var _studentsTemp = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Student>>()
val studentsTemp: LiveData<MutableList<Student>> get() = _studentsTemp
init {
        _studentsTemp.value = mutableListOf<Student>()
}
```

Observer is only being called when the application starts i.e. when ViewModel is created i.e. when init block runs in View Model.

Comment: For every other case observer is working. Except for this case.

Comment: in fragments you should use `viewLifecycleOwner` instead of `this`

Comment: @IR42 alright thanks. Could you please also explain why we use `binding.lifecycleowner = this` in Fragments when using ViewModels? I'm new to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a `MutableList` in your `MutableLiveData`. Note that if you add or remove items from your `MutableList` this will NOT trigger the observer. To trigger the observer you have to update the `LiveData` variable.

So this will not trigger the observer

```
studentsTemp.value?.add(student)
```

but this will

```
studentsTemp.value = studentsTemp.value?.add(student) ?: mutableListOf(studen)
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much for bringing my attention to it. I just added the line `_studentsTemp.value = _studentsTemp.value` after the add function and it triggered the observer.